# ownCloud vs NextCloud?

Tags: cloud, open-source, owncloud, nextcloud

I know NextCloud is forked from ownCloud. 
What are the differences between them?

Comment: This will probably get closed as opinion based but some reasons that may assist:  a bunch of core opencloud devs moved to nextcloud;  opencloud closed their US office days after the fork, and opencloud's enterprise platform isn't open source, but nextcloud's is.

Comment: OWNcloud, not "opencloud."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What happened was that owncloud was dual licensed product so there were user and enterprise editions. Some developers didn't feel like owncloud valued the community enough and didn't like the dual license model, so they left the project & forked owncloud to create nextcloud.

Nextcloud is the same for home and enterprise users since it is all AGPL licensed code.

As for a recommendation, I would go with nextcloud since the community is behind them more, and of the apps I used in owncloud work in nextcloud. Also they are pushing for integrations like collabora (online collaborative editing) and speed.me video conferencing.

Answer (score 5):

Nextcloud has made tremendous progress since the fork, and there are a lot of differences now. The licensing is different and the feature set of each is different, as well as the community behind each. You can see a report of all the differences here:

https://civihosting.com/blog/nextcloud-vs-owncloud/

Then you can make your own, educated, decision as to which is for you.